# Xamarin forms toolbar items occurs two times in the tabbed page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I added a toolbar item of name refresh in tabbed page, below is the code of the tabbed page

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xapp;assembly=Xapp"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="Xapp.HomePage">
    
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="Refresh" Text="Refresh" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="report">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:ReportPage>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="In:" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CountIn}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Text="Out:" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CountOut}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Text="Date:" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding createdon}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </local:ReportPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
 
        <NavigationPage Title="history">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:HistoryPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
   
</TabbedPage>
```

the problem is the refresh appears two times in the toolbar as shown in the image below:

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **MainPage** of App is a **TabbedPage** . You don't need to set it as **NavigationPage** . in App.

Modify the code in App.Xaml.CS

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MainPage = new HomePage();
}
```

### Update

It is not a good design to navigate from a **ContentPage** to **TabbedPage**  .

So modify the code to

```
App.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();
```

instead of `page.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());`

Comment: the main page is a  Content page navigates to the tabbed page, that has the above code.

Comment: Sorry for the question, Can you give me a name of tutorial  or book to learn  xamarin

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/